# Use of picture element as a container instead of a div

Tags: html, picturefill

```
<div class="container">
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="A Photo"/>
</div>
```

According to the [picture element specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/embedded-content.html#the-picture-element):

> Zero or more source elements, followed by one img element, optionally
> intermixed with script-supporting elements.
>
> The picture element is a container which provides multiple sources to
> its contained img element...  It represents its children.

Therefore, is it safe to assume that the following HTML is more semantically correct?

```
<picture>
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="A Photo"/>
</picture>
```

Comment: for me this looks perfectly fine, but the question arises: who do you expect to care about it?

Comment: @johnSmith You are right! Actually the question sprung from the fact that I have seen a lot of articles that say in bold "do not use `picture`, it is `img` that you need". I have an HTML section full of divs which I want to relieve... and here it is.

Comment: question remains, who cares(as users dont look at the elements)? Because if you do this for better SEO you should rather think of adding a title attribute to img ;)

Comment: @johnSmith I did not think of SEO yet but surely this is essential, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The semantically corect contaner for an image element is the figure element - documentation - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/figure

```
 <figure>
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="A Photo"/>
</figure>
```

This element has an optional figcaption element that can be either the first child or the last child - to provide a caption (contextual text related to the image).

as the first child (above the image

```
 <figure>
  <figcaption>A photo</figcaption>
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="A Photo"/>
</figure>
```

As the last child - below the image

```
 <figure>
  <img src="photo.jpg" alt="A Photo"/>
  <figcaption>A photo</figcaption>
</figure>
```

Note that you can style the figure and contained figcaption and img elements to be whatever style you want.

```css
figure {
 text-align: center;
}

figcaption {
  margin-bottom: 8px;
  color: green;
}
figure img {
 border: solid 1px green;
 padding: 4px;
 border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
 <figure>
  <figcaption>A Fluffy kitten</figcaption>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/originals/3e/6b/cd/3e6bcdc46881f5355163f9783c44a985.jpg" alt="A fluffy kitten" width="150"/>
</figure>
```

Answer (score 2):

No, the second version is not more semantically correct because the picture element is intended to be used when there are multiple sources files that might be used under different circumstances.

HTML Specification:

> The *picture* element is a container which provides multiple sources to its contained *img* element to allow authors to declaratively control or give hints to the user agent about which image resource to use, based on the screen pixel density, viewport size, image format, and other factors. It represents its children.

It would be best if you use the image tag on its own. You can wrap it in a div for styling or spacing purposes, but, unless you plan on displaying content programmatically, use it alone if it is possible.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is what puzzles me: It refers to it as a "container" and above that paragraph, it especially mentions "Zero or more `source` elements". My edge case is of "zero" `source` elements.

Comment: Why is it necessary for you to use divs that wrap around the img elements instead of using the img elements on their own?

Comment: That is a good question because I am not sure that this is the only way of doing it: I am using the [foundation's xy-grid](https://get.foundation/sites/docs/xy-grid.html) in order to put an icon next to a heading and outside of the flow of the text. Therefore I created 1 column for the `<img>` and 11 columns for the text. If I apply the class directly to the `<img>` the image appears stretched, therefore I need the container.

Comment: I just found [another reason!](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2013/09/responsive-images-performance-problem-case-study/) It is a fairly old article, but quite descent. It is based on this [ancient one.](https://alistapart.com/article/creating-intrinsic-ratios-for-video/) History can teach us the future! :-D